# css3 -moz-border-image isn't working?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm new to CSS3 and HTML and I'm trying to get the `-moz-border-image` to show but it isn't showing instead it shows `border: 20px solid red;` even if i get rid of the `border` code it still wont show the `-moz-border-image` because it needs a border-width to show and all the code is in `.sampleDiv2`.

I'm using a firefox browser. Thanks

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>CSS3 borders</title>

  <style>
    body {
      margin-left: 40px;
    }
    .sampleDiv {
      background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .2);
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border-width: 16px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: red;
      border-radius: 25px 50px 100px 200px;
    }
    .sampleDiv2 {
      background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .2);
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      -moz-border-image: url( http://s28.postimg.org/hs0wu7rvx/star_frame.png) 50 50 50 round;
      border: 20px solid red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>CSS3 borders</h1>
  <div class="sampleDiv"></div>
  <br/>
  <div class="sampleDiv2"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is what should happen to `.sampleDiv2` because i did `50px` for the slice property , `50px` for how much of the width i wont to use, i did `50px` for the outside border (What i am talking about wont match the picture because im guessing it's big) and `round` to go around the border.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work.

```
 body {
      margin-left: 40px;
    }
    .sampleDiv {
      background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .2);
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border-width: 16px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: red;
      border-radius: 25px 50px 100px 200px;
    }
    .sampleDiv2 {
      background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .2);
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      -moz-border-image:url("http://s28.postimg.org/hs0wu7rvx/star_frame.png") 30 30 repeat; /* Old Firefox */
  -webkit-border-image:url("http://s28.postimg.org/hs0wu7rvx/star_frame.png") 30 30 repeat; /* Safari */
  -o-border-image:url("http://s28.postimg.org/hs0wu7rvx/star_frame.png") 30 30 repeat; /* Opera */
  border-image:url("http://s28.postimg.org/hs0wu7rvx/star_frame.png") 30 30 repeat;
    }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kzoydpwL/

EDIT: You can learn about `border-image` at [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image)...

The major problem you had with your code was that you didn't even provide an image link. http://postimg.org/image/3ll5yzh0p/ is not a direct link to the image while http://s28.postimg.org/hs0wu7rvx/star_frame.png is.

Comment: @jbutler483 I have now provided a brief explanation.

Comment: i added the image link to the code snippet i provided and it still wont work on top of that the jsfiddle link is only showing the the 10% of the color red? and i provided what should happen if my `-moz-border-image` did work

Comment: I added some more information which says "even if i get rid of the`border` code it still wont show the `-moz-border-image` because it needs a border-width to show"